# gulp.src /*/*.ext и gulp.dest

Tags: gulp

```
gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src('./assets/pug/*/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/'))
})
```

при gulp.dest в assets сохраняются `*/*.pug`, а хочется чтобы сохранялись просто `*.pug`. такое возможно сделать? если да, то как?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24658011/4928642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten

   ```
   const flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

   gulp.task('pug', function () {
     return gulp.src('./assets/pug/*/*.pug')
       .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))
       .pipe(flatten())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/'))
   })
   ```
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename

   ```
   const rename = require('gulp-rename');

   gulp.task('pug', function () {
     return gulp.src('./assets/pug/*/*.pug')
       .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))
       .pipe(rename({dirname: ''}))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/'))
   })
   ```

Comment: первый ответ из той темы помог, gulp-rename прост был установлен уже

Comment: ну rename - так rename... дополнил ответ.

Comment: ответ принимать будешь?

Comment: извините) принял

Comment: ага, вижу, спасибо!